# What happens with memory when we reassign value to char pointer?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I wonder what happens inside the memory when we do something like this

```
  char *s;
  s = "Text";
  s = "Another Text";
```

If I'm getting it right, by assigning string to char pointer memory is dynamically allocated. So according to my understanding assignment expression

```
  s = "Text";
```

equals to

```
  s = (char *) malloc(5); // "Text" + '\0'
  strcpy(s, "Text");
```

Well, this way we can easily free memory by using

```
  free(s);
```

But... After reassigning same pointer to another value, it allocates new memory segment to store that value.

```
  s = "Text";
  printf("\n(%p) s = \"%s\"", s, s);

  s = "Another Text";
  printf("\n(%p) s = \"%s\"", s, s);
```

Output:

```
  (0x400614) s = "Text"
  (0x400628) s = "Another Text"
```

That means that address of old value is not accessible to us any longer and we can't free that any more. Another call to `free(s);` will probably deallocate only last memory segment used by that pointer.

**My question is:** If we reassign same char pointer over and over again, does it consume more and more program memory during run-time or that garbage somehow gets automatically freed?

I hope that was enough to demonstrate my problem, couldn't think better example. If something's not clear enough please ask for additional clarification.

Comment: Not even close.  The sequence of statements  `s = "Text"; s = "Another Text";`   does not involve any dynamic memory allocation at all.    The *only* circumstance where explicit deallocation is required is after memory has been dynamically allocated.   In the case you discuss, there is no dynamic allocation of memory, so no need for deallocation AT ALL.

Comment: @Peter Got it. What if we read strings at run-time from file and assign to pointer instead of using compile-time stored values? Guess, dynamic allocation is required in that case because compiler cant know what we're about to load from file and what amount of memory will be consumed.

Comment: @Peter On another thought, that wont be even possible to read string from file or stdin to `char *` pointer with no previous malloc/calloc to that pointer.

Comment: Not so.   An array can be created with automatic storage duration.   If that array is passed as an argument to a function expecting a pointer, then that function receives the address of the first element of that array.   Again, there is no need for explicit allocation using `malloc()` and related functions, or release using `free()`.   You really need to get a decent introductory text on C, and spend the time to read it,  rather than GUESSING INCORRECTLY about how things work in C.

Comment: @Peter, Yeah, you're right about that. I really have to read more on that subject. But you lost me on first part of your comment. If I guessed incorrectly that `malloc` is required to read from file or stdin, tell me why I can't do `char *s; fgets(s, 100, stdin);`? That piece of code doesn't work with no malloc before reading from stdin. Same happens when using `fscanf` or `fread` to read string from file in nil `char *`. Tried in compiler, it's not a guess this time.

Comment: Because a pointer and an array are completely different things even though a pointer can be used, in some contexts, like an array.   Even accessing the value of an uninitialised pointer gives undefined behaviour.   Dereferencing a null pointer (which is not the same thing as an uninitalised pointer) also gives undefined behaviour.    `s` needs to be initialised to *something* so `fgets(s, 100, stdin)` can act AS IF `s` is the first element of an array with `100` elements.  `malloc()` provides one option to achieve that.  It is not the only way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it starts with false premises about how C works, and seeks explanations of problems that arise when writing code based on those false premises. It is difficult for anyone to give a useful answer. The OP needs to spend time reading an introductory text in C, rather than relying on guesswork, producing code with undefined behaviour, and then seeking explanations of that undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. It is just the assignment and it does not allocate any memory. In your example you assign the pointer with the addresses of the string literals. String literals are created compile time and placed in the read only memory

You do now allocate any memory by assigning the pointer

Comment: Oh, so they are statically allocated during compiling, not at run-time? In that case, I don't need to worry about freeing it, right?

Comment: Re "*I don't need to worry about freeing it, right?*", You can't free the strings created by string literals.

Comment: @ikegami thanx, that's confirmation I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not equal to doing a malloc. What's happening is that the string literal is stored in a read only part of memory. And it's not the assignment of a pointer that does the allocation. All string literals in a program are already allocated from start.

It might be worth mentioning that they are not strictly speaking stored in read only memory, but they might be and writing to a string literal is undefined behavior.

You cannot and should not call free on a string literal. Well, you can, but the program will likely crash.

Comment: So, strings are stored somewhere during compile-time and assignments only give addresses of those strings in memory to pointers, right?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Yes

Answer (score 1):

- With no optimization, compiler will reserve two distinct memory space for string literals "text1" and "text2".
- If assignment lines are very consecutive as in your question and if nothing is done after the first assignment line —assuming compiling with optimization— compiler, most probably, will not allocate any space for the first string literal nor will produce any opcode for the first assignment line.